# Convert date string to date with timezone using moment timezone js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I need to convert a date string to PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) and the resutant datetime must be displayed in local time.

I tried with

```
console.log(moment.tz("16:23:42 Sep 27, 2018 PDT", 'HH:mm:ss MMM DD, YYYY PDT',"PDT").format());
```

When I run the above code it displays

```
2018-09-27T16:23:42Z
```

Which is not the local time. The local time of its equivalent must be different. How do I get the local time of the date string specified.

In otherwords, I mean to say like this https://forums.asp.net/t/1552114.aspx?Convert+Datetime+String+from+PDT+to+IST+local+time+datetime+string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, i think it will work

first get timezone offset `timeZoneId` is your time zone.

```
const offset =  moment['tz'](moment(new Date()), timeZoneId).utcOffset() * 60000;
```

secondly create new datefrom your date and  your offset

```
console.log(new Date(new Date(yourDateString).getTime() + offset))
```

and yes `yourDateString` is your date string, better works for date obj, but w/e

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var desiredFormat = "HH:mm:ss MMM DD, YYYY";
var timeToBeConverted = moment("16:23:42 Sep 27, 2018", desiredFormat);
var timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";

console.log(timeToBeConverted.tz(timeZone).format(desiredFormat) + " PDT");
```

The timezone you provide cannot be "PDT". If you use `moment.tz.names()` in the console you'll get a list of valid timezone names. In the example above I've used "America/Los_Angeles", but any region that observes PDT is fine.